# Query For Hierarchy Order In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My Actual Table :

```
--------------------------------------------------
      Col1      |      Col2         |     Col3      |
--------------------------------------------------
     1                A                  1
     6                F                  2
     3                C                  4     
     2                B                  1
     5                E                  3
     4                D                  2
```

Expected Result :

```
------------------
|Columns Should Be|
------------------
A     B    F    D   C   E
```

I need SQL query for this hierarchical logic.I have to get resultant logic using col 1 and col3 .Kindly help me out for this query.

Comment: plsql is for Oracle, but SQL Server is tagged. Can you correct?

Comment: I need from SQL query.

Comment: I'd advise going at least a little way to resolving this yourself. What have you tried and why isn't it working. You've given us very little information and even less guidance on what your input and expected output is.

Comment: i have to build col2 as result using Col1 and Col3. I need a logic for this

Comment: @Kapil: What you are comparing in col1 and col3. What if they are equal, what if col1 > col3 etc...

Comment: I think you might be need the [pivot function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) of SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I've just read your replies, I believe this is what you're after;

```
CREATE TABLE #TempData (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(1), Col3 int)
INSERT INTO #TempData (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
('1','A','1')
,('6','F','4')
,('6','C','2')
,('2','B','1')
,('5','E','3')
,('4','D','5')

SELECT
Col2
FROM #TempData
GROUP BY Col2
ORDER BY SUM(Col1)+SUM(Col3)

DROP TABLE #TempData
```

Comment: Thanks But I have mistakenly posted wrong question. kindly check my question now and help me out

Comment: Ok, this question has been a mess from the start. I'm going to advise you take a look at the UNPIVOT command and not ask vague questions when you have made no (apparent) attempt to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table (col1 int, col2 varchar(1), col3 int)
insert into @table (col1,col3)
values
(1,  1),
(6,  4),
(3,  2),   
(2,  1),
(5,  3),
(4,  2)

/*
      Col1      |      Col2         |     Col3      |
--------------------------------------------------
     1                A                  1
     6                F                  4
     3                C                  2     
     2                B                  1
     5                E                  3
     4                D                  5
*/
select  col1,
        case 
            when col1 > col3 then char(col1 + 64)
            else char(col3 + 64)
        end as col2,
        col3
from    @table
```

Answer (score 0):

in Sql server you may try this,

```
declare @t table (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(1), Col3 int)
INSERT INTO @t (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
('1','A','1')
,('6','F','2')
,('3','C','4')
,('2','B','1')
,('5','E','3')
,('4','D','2')
declare @str as varchar(100)=''
;with t as(select top 1 col1,col2,col3 from @t union all select t1.col1, t1.col2,t1.col3 from @t t1,t 
where (t1.Col1!=t.Col1 and t1.Col3=t.Col1) )

select @str=@str+'  '+col2 from t
select @str as col
```